# Sails JS policy doesn't respond

Tags: sails.js, jwt

I'm facing an issue with a Sails Js Policy I have made. It is supposed to act as middleware between any sent request and the aimed controller.

**Expected**

The JWT sent in the header of the request should be verified, the playload decoded and it's content assigned to a `req.user` variable reachable from any controller.

**Problem**

I don't receive any answer (not even 500) from my backend server when I send a Barear Token authorization type request with a precedently generated JWT (*with postman*).

**What I've built**

The logged-in policy :

```
module.exports = async function (req, res, next) {

  var token;

  // Check if authorization header is present
  if(req.headers && req.headers.authorization) {

    // If so, isolate each parts
    var parts = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');
    if(parts.length == 2) {
        var scheme = parts[0];
        var credentials = parts[1];

        if(/^Bearer$/i.test(scheme)) {
            token = credentials;
        }
    } else {... error return ...}

    // If all test succeed, use TokenService.verify
    var decoded = TokenService.verify(token);

    User.findOne({id: decoded.id}).exec((error, user) => {
      if (error) return res.serverError(error)
      if (user) {
        req.token = decoded;
        next();
      }
    });
};
```

My Token Service :

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const tokenSecret = 'secretissecret';

module.exports = {

[...]

verify: token => jwt.verify(token, tokenSecret)
};
```

The policies config:

```
module.exports.policies = {

'*': 'is-logged-in',

// Bypass the `is-logged-in` policy for:
'entrance/*': true,
'account/logout': true,
'deliver-contact-form-message': true,

};
```

The simplest aimed controller

```
module.exports = {

[Actions 2 description, no-inputs, exits]

 fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

   // Look up by the user.id
   var userRecord = await User.findOne({ id: this.req.token.id}) <== Fix here

   // If there was no matching user, respond thru the "unfound" exit.
   if(!userRecord) {
     throw 'unfound';
   }    

   return exits.success({
     user: userRecord
   });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to register your policy in config/policies.js

Sample from sails web app template:

```
module.exports.policies = {

    '*': 'is-logged-in',

  // Bypass the `is-logged-in` policy for:
  'entrance/*': true,
  'account/logout': true,
  'view-homepage-or-redirect': true,
  'deliver-contact-form-message': true,

};
```

Comment: That was an oversight, I've just edited the post. The config file was also built.

Comment: My policy works now well (I've edited the post), but in the controller I can't recover my decoded token that I've assigned to the `req.token` parameter => It is undefined. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem this way.

To access the request `token` object in Actions2, I used `this.req.token`.